# Strange TypeError when migrating database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

After migrating my database a few times, I began to see this error appear on my local server.  If I clear the database and re-create it, there is no error, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the way my models are written.

I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/hagandh/Documents/GitHub/pair-site/pair-site/db_repository/versions/006_migration.py",       line 9, in <module>
    Column('id', INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

From this model:

```
class Application(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
```

I don't understand what the error is telling me.  I assume it is something with the way I am defining an integer, however I have never had this problem before.  What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INTEGER` type doesn't take any arguments.  Remove the `display_width=11` argument from that line in the migration script.